# Limit camera rotation- Unity Clamp Quaternion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I have this code that allows a camera to rotate through an input from the touch screen, I need to lock the rotation in a specific range. I tried to use the "Math.Clamp" unsuccessfully. Can someone help me?

I tried to enter this string, but the visual got an error message that says "*Unable to convert from 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'float'*"

```
rotationY  = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, -30, 30);
```

I leave you here the code that allows the camera to run without a limit.
Thanks everyone for the help

```
 private Touch touch;
    private Vector2 touchPosition;
    private Quaternion rotationY;
    private float rotateSpeedModifier = 0.01f;
    //public float yPos;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                    rotationY = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -touch.deltaPosition.x * rotateSpeedModifier, 0f);
                    transform.rotation = rotationY * transform.rotation;
                    Debug.Log(rotationY * transform.rotation);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't clamp a `Quaternion`.

You could however rather store the **float** of the angle you already rotated and clamp that instead:

```
private Touch touch;
private Vector2 touchPosition;
private float rotationY;
private float rotateSpeedModifier = 0.01f;

private Quaternion originalRotation;

private void Start ()
{
    originalRotation = transform.rotation;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {       
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            rotationY -= touch.deltaPosition.x * rotateSpeedModifier;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, -30, 30);

            transform.rotation = originalRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationY, 0);
        }
    }
}
```